# On press enter value not submitting in text input

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular11

When pressing enter after writing something in input box field, value is not getting submitted in angular 8.

Which event should I use in order to make it work properly?

Comment: please share your code sample

Comment: if you has a form and a button (For Angular the buttons by defect are type "submit") should work :(

Comment: It's just input field which on enter press value should pass to function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(keyup.enter)` for that.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljiak4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks. Resolved my query...